# Is there a way to configure a specific consumer when using ConfigureEndpoints method in MassTransit?

Tags: c#, masstransit

I've got a lot of consumers and I don't want to configure each of them manually, so I use methods `AddConsumers` and `ConfigureEndpoints`.
Now I need to configure a repeat policy for one of the consumers.
If additionally call the `ReceiveEndPoint` method (before or after calling `ConfigureEndpoints`), the exception "A receive endpoint with the same key was already added" is thrown.

Is it possible to combine convention based endpoints configuration and custom configuration of individual consumers?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working:

```cs
    services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddConsumers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            // this consumer is also present in the assembly:
            cfg.AddConsumer<SpecificConsumer>(x => x.UseRetry(r => r.Immediate(5)));
            cfg.AddBus(sp => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x => x.ConfigureEndpoints(sp)));
        });
```